# Algorithm of choosing several items with best characteristics to maximize profit

Tags: algorithm, linear-programming

Let's say we have items `A1-A10` with different characteristics. For example `A1 (x1=4; x2=2; x3=1; x4=3)`. And we have 5 categories `C1-C5` to put items into.

```
x1 - matters for category 1, 
x2 - for category 2, 
x3 - category 3, 
x4 - categories 4 and 5.
```

It must be at least one item in each category.

Our goal is to put items to different categories that way - so the output is maximum.

Example:

```
Let's say we have 4 items A1 (x1=3; x2=1; x3=1), A2 (x1=2; x2=1; x3=2); 
A3 (x1=1; x2=1; x3=3); A4(x1=1; x2=3; x3=1) and 3 categories C1(x1); 
C2(x2); C3(x3).
```

Here the best way to put A1 to category C1 (+3 on output); A3 to category C3 (+3 on output); A4 to category C2 (+3 on output) and A2 to either to category C1 or C3 (+2 on output). So our output will be 11.

[image: Best solution of given example.]

Here's also the picture with a bad solution of given example with output 4.
[image: Worst solution of given example.]

But that was the easy example. I have some much complex to solve.

Comment: You should study [How to ask question on Stack OverFlow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). SO is not for doing your homework.

Comment: It's not for homework. I need to implement it in my program. I just desperate after few hours of googling. I'll read the article about asking questions, thanks.

Comment: it's third time I'm seeing this question about 'characteristics' and 'categories'. Each time it's unclear and goes nowhere

Comment: Added some pictures for better understanding.